# MongoDB mm/dd/yy based $gte & $le

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

First of all, pardon me for my English.

Now, the issue I'm facing is, the existing database has a column named "Date" inside "startOn" Object. It means, it makes like "startOn.Date" and it has data like `yyyy/dd/mm`. Suppose, I have a record that is like: `2013/06/05`. The thing is, I need to get data from after `2 days` to `7 days`. That means `$gte: +2 days` and `$le: +7 days`.

I tried couple of ways like

```
$gte: use("RFCtoClean")(new Date(year, month - 1, day + 2)),
```

RFCtoClean is:

```
function RFCtoClean(d) {
d = new Date(d);
return d.getUTCFullYear() + "/" + pad(d.getUTCDate()) + "/" + pad(d.getUTCMonth() + 1);}
```

This returns nothing but even the following code's callback returns `undefined`.

```
var currentDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                var day = currentDate.getDate()
                , month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
                , year = currentDate.getFullYear();
Event.find({
                    author: user_id,
                    "startOn.Date": {
                        $gte: use("RFCtoClean")(new Date(year, month - 1, day + 2)),
                        $le: use("RFCtoClean")(new Date(year, month - 1, day + 7))
                    }
                }, '_id title location startOn attendees', {
                    limit: limit
                })
                .sort({_id: -1})
                .execFind(function(err, events) {
    // events variable is undefined here and empty err object,
    });
```

can anyone help me to come out of it?

Comment: Are you saying that the document contains date as a string?  "YYYY/MM/DD"? and you want to manipulate it as a date type and not a string?

Comment: Is it really "YYYY/DD/MM" and not "YYYY/MM/DD"?  If it was MM/DD then you could actually just compare strings for this, but if it's DD/MM like you suggest, you're going to have to use $where and cast to dates.  If the field is a string, mongo will treat it like a string, not a date, and for example, the string "2000/31/01" is "greater than" "2000/01/02" as the day comes first in the string, even though the month is higher, whereas "2000/01/31" would be "less than" "2000/02/01".

Comment: If the dates are in this completely bizarre and non-standard format then isn't the real problem data validity? I.e. nothing reads dates in this format - so shouldn't the task be to fix the entire collection to have dates in a "normal" format and cleanse it incoming from now on?

Comment: I'd wait to get confirmation - d = new Date(d); implies that calling Date with this string returns a valid date and that means it has to be "YYYY/MM/DD" so maybe it's just a "typo"?  OP would have to reply.  @HamzaWaqas can you confirm what the string format is?

Comment: This title is misleading. The format stated in the title doesn't match that used in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You get a date as a string, like this `"2013/06/05"` - it looks like you know how to get two more string that are two days before or seven days after, right?     So you will have:

```
from="2013/06/03;
till="2013/06/12;
```

Now just do a regular find:

```
db.data.find( {
               "startonDate" : {
                   $gte: from,
                   $lte: till
               } 
            } );
```

Comment: This *would* work if the date strings were formatted "yyyy/mm/dd", but dates seem to be formatted (oddly) as "yyyy/dd/mm".  If this is really the case, then day would take precedence over month, meaning simple string comparison will fail.